# Sending Message Headers with Spring AMQP outbound gateway

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-integration

I have used Spring Amqp Outbound Gateway integration to send request to a third party web service. Below shown is my gateway interface.

```
public interface AccountManagerGateway {

    public RetrieveAccountResponse retrieveAccount(RetrieveAccountRequest request);
}
```

I need to know how to send custom Message Headers with the gateway call.

```
Ex:- "AccountID" in the header
```

I did some google searches but couldn't find a solution. May be I'm doing the search in a wrong context or a wrong direction. I'm expecting your kind support on this.

Please let me know if you need more info. I didn't post my integration-context xml in here because then the post will get lengthy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation about gateways](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway).

For example:

```
public RetrieveAccountResponse retrieveAccount(RetrieveAccountRequest request,
               @Header("AccountId") String accountId);
```

By default, user-defined headers are not sent over AMQP so you need to configure the `mapped-request-headers` on the outbound gateway; something like

```
mapped-request-headers="STANDARD_REQUEST_HEADERS,AccountId"
```

Again, refer to [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-message-headers).